# How to find the top 10 most popular values in a comma separated list with PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, count

I am new to all of this and I have Googled and searched on here, but to no avail. Using google and some of the responses here, I've managed to solve a separate problem, but this is what I'm really interested in and am wondering if this is even possible/how to accomplish it.

I have mysql table that looks like this:

```
id       type of game       players               timestamp
1        poker              a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h       2011-10-08 08:00:00
2        fencing            i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p       2011-10-08 08:05:00
3        tennis             a,e,k,g,p,o,d,z       2011-10-08 08:10:00
4        football           x,y,f,b               2011-10-08 08:15:00
```

There are 7 types of games, and either 4 or 8 players separated by commas for each gametype. 
However, the players are IRC nicknames so potentially there could be new players with unique nicknames all the time.

What I am trying to do is look in the players column of the entire table and find the top 10 players in terms of games played, regardless of the gametype, and print it out to a website in this format, e.g.:

## Top 10 Players:

1. a (50 games played)
2. f (39 games played)
3. o (20 games played)
   ......

10 g (2 games played)

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated! Honestly, without this website I would not have even come this fair in my project!

Comment: You really should read about [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Your database schema as such is not very usable...

Comment: if players would be in a different table (like it should if you normalize your DB), it would be pretty easy, now it's pretty hard.

Comment: Read this question and answer **Is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: One of the reasons is (from that answer): **Hard to count elements in the list, or do other aggregate queries.**, exactly what you want. You can find a way to do it, (using `FIND_IN_SET()` function) but it will be real slow. With 1000 users and 100k+ rows in this table, it will bring your MySQL server to its kness.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you don't keep a list of the players for each game in the same table, but rather implement a relationship between a `games` table and a `players` table.

The new model could look like:

TABLE Games:

```
id       type of game       timestamp
1        poker              2011-10-08 08:00:00
2        fencing            2011-10-08 08:05:00
3        tennis             2011-10-08 08:10:00
4        football           2011-10-08 08:15:00
```

TABLE Players:

```
id       name
1        a
2        b
3        c
..       ..
```

TABLE PlayersInGame:

```
id      idGame     idPlayer   current
1       1          1          true      //Player a is currently playing poker
```

When a player starts a game, add it to the `PlayersInGame` table.

When a player exits a game, set the `current` status to `false`.

To retrieve the number of games played by a player, query the `PlayersInGame` table.

```
SELECT COUNT FROM PlayersInGame WHERE idPlayer=1
```

For faster processing you need to de-normalize(not actually denormalization, but i don't know what else to call it) the table and keep track of the number of games for each player in the `Players` table. This would increase the table size but provide better speed.

So insert column games played in Players and query after that:

```
SELECT * FROM Players ORDER BY games_played DESC LIMIT 10
```

EDIT:

As Ilmari Karonen pointed out, to gain speed from this you must create an `INDEX` for the column `games_played`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree with your answer that for a small number of players the denormalization isn't that beneficial, however for a small number of players it also doesn't add that much extra storage, does it? I'll edit my answer to also specify indexing the column.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to look into this. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a *huge* number of players, you probably don't need the denormalization step suggested at the end of [Luchian Grigore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696690/how-to-find-the-top-10-most-popular-values-in-a-comma-separated-list-with-php-m/7696733#7696733).  Assuming tables structured as he initially suggests, and an index on `PlayersInGame (idPlayer)`, the following query should be reasonably fast:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(*) AS games_played
FROM
  PlayersInGame AS g
  JOIN Players AS p ON p.id = g.idPlayer
GROUP BY g.idPlayer
ORDER BY games_played DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This does require a filesort, but only on the grouped data, so its performance will only depend on the number of players, not the number of games played.

Ps. If you do end up adding an explicit `games_played` column to the player table, do remember to create an index on it — otherwise the denormalization will gain you nothing.

Comment: Thank you! The database will at all times include under 180 players.